# Trouble trying to find the time efficiency of a recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm learning time efficiency of algorithms and have become stuck at trying to analyse recursive algorithms. I currently have an algorithm that just basically traverses a binary search tree and puts each node into an array.

```
placeIntoArray(root, array[]a, int i) {
    if (root.left != null) {
       i = placeIntoArray(root.left, a, i);
    }
    a[i] = root;
    i++;
    if (root.right != null) {
       i = placeIntoArray(root.right, a, i);
    }
    return i;
}
```

If I had to guess I'd think it was in the class of O(n) since it's just touching each node of placing it into an array, but I'm not sure how to analyse it properly.. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time complexity of the problem for the array with the size of `n` is `T(n) = T(number of the elements in the root.left) + T(number of the elements in the root.right) + c` that `c` is constant. In two extreme scenarios, it would be `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + c` (completely balanced) which means `T(n) = Theta(n)` or `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(1) + c` (completely unblanced) that means `T(n) = Theta(n)`. If you consider the other cases, you will find that `T(n) = Theta(n)`.

Comment: so how would I express this time complexity in big O? sorry if I am missing something here

Comment: @mss If `T(n) = Theta(n)`, it will be `O(n)` as well.